# Defining function with function object passed in as argument

Tags: python, function, object

I'm using the internet to teach myself something useful like python. The resources I've been using so far 'Think python' by Downey and 'Learning Python' by Lutz. I was first introduced to python the Udacity programme on computer science, and have been teaching myself from here on in. I'm a coding neophyte and this is the first language I've attempted to learn.

My problem, is one posed by Downey in 'think python' and is defining a function that takes a function object as one of its arguments along with the number n.

It was introduced in the recursive programming chapter and has been giving me kittens.

My code so far:

```
    def print_string(s):
        print (s)
        return

    def do_n(f , n):
        if n <=0:
            return
        f
        do_n(f, n-1)
```

now I've been trying this with a simple predefined print function called print_ string that takes argument(s).

I save the script in a file called recursive.py and run it in IDLE then after it's run i call do_n with the following do_n(print_string('test'), 6)

I expect to print the sample string 'test' `6` times but it only prints once. There appears to be no recursion.

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated because i can't really afford to sign up with Udacity or anything else this is just me & the internet vs python. TIA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This came to me to review as your first post. I think you need to edit your post a little.  In particular - you might need to show how you call `do_n` and make it clear that you're passing in the function `print_string` as `f` (I think that's what you mean).  Also - you need to say what argument(s) `print_string` takes - i.e. is it `print_string(arg1)` or `print_string(arg1, arg2, .... arg 20...)`

Comment: hope the edit makes it a little clearer Richard, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Ahh - yes it does - and makes the problem a little more interesting.  Try putting a `print('been here')` after `f` in your `do_n` function now.  You will see that it is recursing.  So - why do you only see one `print_string` ... ? Think about when the function `print_string` is actually being called... I'll edit my answer to explain, but do recommend you try it yourself first and compare what I do with my answer below to what you're doing.  Note - where I put `f(n)`, you could put `f('test')` to see the output I think you're expecting

Comment: As a further test - try calling `do_n(print_string('test'), 0)` . I expect you will also be surprised by the result and it might help you to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very nearly there.  I  think the problem is with your call to `f` in your method.  Don't forget - you have passed in a *function* as `f`, not a *function call*.  So, when you have `f` in your `do_n` function, it does nothing.  If you did `f()` it would actually call f (with no arguments, which may or may not be allowed) and, possibly better, if you did `f(n)` it should call `print_string` with `n` as the argument.  I mocked up a little demo to get you going:

```
def print_string(arg1=''):
    # mimicing your "pre-defined" function
    # Note I've put a default value in arg1 so that you
    # can call it without an argument to illustrate the priciple
    print(arg1)    

def do_n(f , n):
    if n <=0:
        return
    f('test')         # This is the line that was close, but not quite right
    do_n(f, n-1)

do_n(print_string,10)
```

---

*** EDIT ***

In response to OP clarification in edit.  The original code was as per the original post, but called with the line

```
do_n(print_string('test'),6)
```

The problem with this is that the `print_string()` function is being before you ever enter `do_n`.  As the `print_string()` function simply prints what it's given (I assume) and returns nothing - you're actually passing `None` into the `do_n` function.

As an aside and to convince yourself that the `print_string` is being evaluated before `do_n` is ever called - try making a single change to your original to say

```
do_n(print_string('test'),0)
```

You might expect to see nothing, but in fact you will see the output `test` as the print_string is still called.

### Solution

To pass a function into another function, you pass its name, but ***don't*** follow it with any brackets or arguments.  In that way, you are passing the function object, not the result of calling that function.

You actually call the function (or indeed pass it on to another function) from within the receiving function where you want it to do something. My example code above still stands.  Note - I pass in `print_string` with no brackets or arguments.

This is a powerful technique - it might take a little thinking to get your head round, but it's worthwhile doing so.  As a rule of thumb - if you see a function name that isn't followed by any brackets, it's being passed as a function object.  If it's followed by brackets, it's being evaluated at that point.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your time, i've tried calling f with empty brackets f() and even with your f(n), i get the same error when i do both that is. 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for all your guidance, i got there eventually. I put in a print statement around f to see that it was recursing. then i put in a print(type(f)) in to see what status f actually had. it was actually non type- until I took the arg out of the print_string call, then things started working. I still had to modify print_string in to empty arg and just give it an output of print 'result'. But the bottom line is that it worked. :-) Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem - glad to help.  Hope you're voyage into learning Python goes well.  With your books, willingness to persevere and a few well phrased questions on here, I'm sure you'll be fine.  P.S. You need to edit the formatting of the code in your example answer to this Q - the indents are too small after the line `if n <= 0` - they must have been in the code you ran though, otherwise it wouldn't have worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is the final code that i ended up with that actually worked.

```
    def print_string():
        print ('result')
        return
    def do_n(f, n):
        if n <=0:
            return
        print(type(f))
        f()
        print('been here')
        do_n(f, n-1) 

    do_n(print_string, 6)
```

The two print calls 'been here' and type(f) were put in to try and understand what was going on with the program and don't need to be there, but i like the reminder of the leap i've made - so they're staying in.